# How to change caption color for a color theme in beamerposter?

Tags: beamer, color, captions, themes

I am facing a problem. In my poster, I use a color theme, for that reason in figure caption comes with green color, that is quite invisible.[image]

Is it possible to change the color?

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=120,scale=1.7,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,xcolor,pgf}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}% text under figure
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %for justify tex
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]



\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{ \centering#2\par}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

\usecolortheme[RGB={180,250,80}]{structure} 
\usetheme[height=0mm]{Rochester} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\begin{textblock}{}(6,3.95)%
\begin{varblock}[42cm]{}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{1.jpg}
\caption{ Individual source location A ($\mathrm{L_{A}}$) .}
\label{1}
\end{figure}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the `caption name` color:

```
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{<color>}
```

For example, you could use

```
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=structure!70!black}
```

[image]

Comment: The above answer didn't work for me, but rummaging through `texdoc` and online search this finally worked: \captionsetup{textfont=black,labelfont=black} (That's in the document's preamble)
Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: `\captionsetup` requires additional packages, (`caption`, for example); using just `black` will produce errors, since just `black` is not a default valid option for `textfont or `labelfont`.

Comment: @JunCTionS For me, Gonzalo's method does work perfectly well